# Redraw glQuads at another position by glTranslate - OpenGL

Tags: c++, c, opengl, 3d, glut

At first I have a simple white rectangular prism like this:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
 glBegin(GL_QUADS);               

      glColor3f(255,255,255);    
      glVertex3f( 0.3, 0, 2.5);//sisi bawah
      glVertex3f(0.5, 0, 2.5);
      glVertex3f(0.5, 0,  2.6);
      glVertex3f( 0.3, 0,  2.6);

      glVertex3f(0.5, 0,  2.6);//sisi kiri
      glVertex3f( 0.3, 0,  2.6);
      glVertex3f( 0.3, 1.5,  2.6);
      glVertex3f(0.5, 1.5,  2.6);

      glVertex3f(0.5, 0, 2.5);//sisi depan
      glVertex3f(0.5, 0,  2.6);
      glVertex3f(0.5, 1.5,  2.6);
      glVertex3f(0.5, 1.5,  2.5);

      glVertex3f( 0.3, 0, 2.5);//sisi belakang
      glVertex3f( 0.3, 0,  2.6);
      glVertex3f( 0.3, 1.5,  2.6);
      glVertex3f( 0.3, 1.5, 2.5);

      glVertex3f( 0.3, 1.5, 2.5);//sisi atas
      glVertex3f(0.5, 1.5, 2.5);
      glVertex3f(0.5, 1.5,  2.6);
      glVertex3f( 0.3, 1.5,  2.6);

      glVertex3f(0.5, 0,  2.5);//sisi kanan
      glVertex3f( 0.3, 0,  2.5);
      glVertex3f( 0.3, 1.5,  2.5);
      glVertex3f(0.5, 1.5,  2.5);

glEnd();
```

Then, I want to draw another rectangular prism like this:

[image]

Can I redraw the another prism just by using `glTranslate` so I don't have to manually insert the numbers?

Comment: The simple answer is "yes"

Comment: Why do you all guys still use immediate mode?

Comment: @Drop Yea, I makes me sad seeing people using deprecated functions.

Comment: @Vallentin so if it's deprecated, could you provide the good ones?

Comment: What do you mean with "could you provide the good ones" and also actually 100% of the code you provided is deprecated.

Comment: You said it's deprecated that indicates the code should be avoided. So, could you show me another better code than this one?

Comment: You should be using vertex buffers using functions such as glGenBuffers, glBindBuffer, glBufferData, glVertexPointer and glDrawArrays.

Comment: In addition to what @SeanBurton has said you should also learn about shaders. If you are doing this as a part of a uni course/module if I were you I`d ask your teacher about when you will start being taught modern Open GL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, create a function to call the draw commands on drawing a prism about its model coordinates, `drawPrism`. Then in the code you can do this:

```
//draw prism 1
glPushMatrix();
glTranslate(x1, y1, z1);
drawPrism();
glPopMatrix();

//draw prism 2
glPushMatrix();
glTranslate(x2, y2, z2);
drawPrism();
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: I don't know what coordinates should be inserted into the 3 parameters x1,y1,z1 in glTranslate.

Comment: That is up to you. These will be the world coordinates. Basically place them in world corrdinates based on the center of mass. It will take some tuning and playing with

Comment: for example, if I want the prism to be centered at (-10, -5, 0) then that is a good starting point for x1, y1, and z1 respectively